# how to not let nav bar push div down

Tags: html, css

In my site I have a responsive nav bar with a header at the top of the page. When the nav bar is opened, the div with the header is pushed down with it.

How is it possible for the nav bar to simply go over top of the div without pushing it down.

[Link to the website](http://www.widgocorp.net/pih/gallery.html)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Nice name Vlad.

`style = 'position:absolute;'` will make it so that the dimensions/position of the element you attach it to do not affect any elements other than its children.

[Mozilla Dev Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: thanks!
I think the divs were not properly positioned one inside another and this was causing issues. I fixed the issue by placing the header inside the div below it.

Comment: Also, `position: fixed` will fixate the element on one on the screen no matter where the window is. Just relative positioning (which is what elements have by default) makes all the elements respect eachother's position and margins.